# Vue.js - Element-UI how to programmatically close MessageBox?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using MessageBox as user login box, I need to programmatically close the box after a successful login, but I can't find anything from the document to enable my doing that.

Please help.

Comment: What code do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`MessageBox.close` method](https://github.com/ElementUI/lib/blob/v2.2.1/message-box.js#L471) that will close the current instance.

```
import { MessageBox } from 'element-ui';

// and later
MessageBox.close()
```

or if you're not using a bundler...

```
ELEMENT.MessageBox.close()
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/L0ejLvmr/6/

Comment: MessageBox.close() closes the box but the modal is untouched.

Comment: @JerryChin I have absolutely no idea what that means

Comment: The underlying layer(dark background) is not vanishing as the MessageBox goes away, I can't give you a demo of what's happening, very sorry, ELEMENT.MessageBox.close() do works!.